# prepare content for rtsp streaming on Darwin

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, darwin

I'll try use Darwin streaming server.
After installation mp4 samples work good. But when i add my files (with same format) it doesn't work.

For example, that's play:

```
rtsp://<ip>:7070/sample_h264_1mbit.mp4
```

and that isn't play:

```
rtsp://<ip>:7070/sintel_trailer-480p.mp4
```

Trailer got from here  http://download.blender.org/durian/trailer/ 
Both files played without Darwin streaming server well (at local machine). That's why I think that sintel_trailer-480p.mp4 isn't broke. Sure i try with other files.

I read docs (http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/0/MA579/en_US/QuickTimeStreamingSrvrAdminGuide.pdf) and still can't find answer. How add files to the Darwing streaming server for rtsp streaming?

UPD.
Error is "Unsupported Media Type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mp4 format file can't play directly from streaming server.
You should add hint information to mp4 file.
mp4box -hint filename.mp4
I forgot download url for mp4box, but you can find easy using google.